# Time optimum controller

Tags: design, control, automotive, feedback, optimization

I have a question regarding time optimization that I would be very grateful if you could guide me on it. The question is moving a car/mass with nonlinear forces acting on it from point A to point B with minimum time and maximum precision. This reminds me of the solution using Pontryagin's maximum principle and a bang-bang controller.

The problem is applying such a theory in Matlab. Also I found a tool called Dymos but I couldn't get it to work as well. Could you maybe guide me (or refer me to some sources) to where there is an actual controller designed for such an application? I think that should be a common problem in robot control but I couldn't find any practical algorithm with real-life scenarios.

I need something applicable to a small RC car (realizable); it should be a feedback controller I think. The car should move on a straight line from point A to B and only location data (1-dimensional) of the moving car is available with precision of 1 cm (every 0.3 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Are the nonlinear forces totally predictable? If so then this *is possible*. All you need to do is go full throttle followed by full brake.

You would use your model of the forces acting on the car to calculate the precise moment of switch over which will bring the car to speed zero at the target point. In rocketry the braking part would be called a "suicide burn".

In the real world you need some wiggle room to account for errors in your sensors and model. A common way to do this would be the same "bang bang" maneuver, but you artificially limit your inputs to 90% of their capability, you then modulate the remaining 10% throughout the maneuver to correct for deviations.

Now.. you can clearly see here that there are a lot downsides to optimizing only for speed and accuracy. It requires careful modeling, tight tolerances, and it will be hard on all the components. You will probably want to compromise some on the speed to reduce wear and greatly simplify the control problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MPC (model predictive control), if you can model the plant then you can use that model to generate predict the output and also achieve optimization. I've only done this for linear controllers but it's my understanding you can also do this for nonlinear controllers, or do a linearization of the nonlinear controller. Implementing these types of controllers are not trivial it took me a few months to gain an understanding of them. You must also have a basic understanding of optimal control.

The controllers themselves are also somewhat expensive to implement as they take more operations in just a simple PID control or other filter.